# find a string in a string using awk

Tags: string, awk

here is column 6 in a file:

```
ttttttttttt
tttttttttt
ttttttttt
tttttttattt
tttttttttt
ttttttttttt
```

how can I use awk to print out lines that include "a"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only want to search the sixth column, use:

```
awk '$6 ~ /a/' file
```

If you want the whole line, any of these should work:

```
awk /a/ file

grep a file

sed '/^[^a]*$/d' file
```

Comment: Your sed solution can be simplified to `sed '/a/!d'`

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to print only those lines in which 6th column contains `a` then this would work -

`awk '$6~/a/' file`

Comment: bad comment deleted

Answer (score 2):

if it is an exact match (which yours is not) you're looking for:

$6 == "a"

http://www.pement.org/awk/awk1line.txt
is an excellent resource

awk can also tell you where the pattern is in the column:

```
awk '{++line_num}{ if ( match($6,"a")) { print "found a at position",RSTART, " line " ,line_num}  }' file
```

though this example will only show the first "a" in column 6; a for loop would be needed to show all instances (I think)

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
gawk '{ if ( $1 ~ /a/ ) { print $1  } }' filename
```

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer to show why it works?